# Jmeter read 2 different csv files in different loops

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Currently, i have a requirement where I need to make sure that the data once read is not read again. Earlier I used to use `HttpSimpleTableServer` when I had to run only one loop with `keep=false`. However now I need to run 2 loops and for which the above option doesn’t work as the same csv is read from the start agin for the second loop. So I was thinking if there is a way to read data from different `csv` files per loop. If not how can I make sure that different data is read from the csv for every loop and no data is ever repeated. My `Jmeter` version is `5.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) component to read the data from CSV files.

Set the `` flag to false to read the data only once.

[image]

You may set the remaining flags based on your need.

[image]

You may add two different CSV Data Set Config elements to work with different CSV files.

If you want to handle this programmatically API documentation will be useful. [API documenation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/CSVDataSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read 2 different files in 2 different loops you should consider going for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead

1. Create 2 files like `file0.csv` and `file1.csv`
2. Once done you will be able to:

   - `${__CSVRead(file${__jm__Thread Group__idx}.csv,0)}` - read first column
   - `${__CSVRead(file${__jm__Thread Group__idx}.csv,1)}` - read second column
   - `${__CSVRead(file${__jm__Thread Group__idx}.csv,next)}` - proceed to next row
   - etc.
3. The __CSVRead() function will proceed to the next file on next [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)